# Android app development extending a java class

Tags: java, class, android-studio

I am creating an app which needs to extend the class `ListActivity` in the main Activity to use `setListAdapter()` function. But when I replace `ActionBarActivity` with `ListActivity`, even if any error is not detected, when I run the application it says

> Can not run due to an error

How can I resolve this problem.

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

DataSource dataSource;
ListView lv;
List<people> peoples;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    dataSource = new DataSource(this);
    dataSource.open();

    peoples = dataSource.getPeople();

    if (peoples.size() == 0) {
        insertData();
        peoples = dataSource.getPeople();
    }

    refreshDisplay();



}
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    dataSource.close();
}

protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    dataSource.open();
}

private void insertData(){
    people pl = new people();

    pl.setName("Uditha");
    pl.setTp("123");
    pl = dataSource.insert(pl);
}

public void refreshDisplay(){


    ArrayAdapter<people> adapter = new itemVievHelper(this, peoples);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    //ArrayAdapter<people> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<people>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, peoples);

}
```

Comment: You aren't providing enough information for anyone to help. You probably need to show us your code and the error it produces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to extend `ListViewActivity` in order to use `ListView`. Just add `ListView` widget to your XML layout, provide an ID for this widget and access it from the `Activity`. For example:

In XML layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <ListView android:id="@+id/my_list_view"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then, you can access this `ListView` inside the `Activity`

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {   
  private ListView myListView;

  @Override   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.my_list_view);
    myListView.setAdapter(...) // set your adapter here
    // perform another operations on myListView   
  } 
}
```

Comment: I am using another layout to display my data. When I tried to insert that layout into ListView it did not work. is it possible of am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It should work. Maybe something is wrong with your adapter? My post contains half-Java and half-pseudocode. You can take a look on a real app using this concept e.g. here: https://github.com/pwittchen/NetworkEvents/tree/master/example